# how display verticall align text middle in datatable?

Tags: html, datatables

How can I vertically align a  in the middle of a fixed height using datatables?
[image]

Comment: how about  vertical-align: middle;

Answer (score 0):

In order to help you, you must share a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) with your case.

If you read [this page](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/complex_header.html) the example has the right vertical align
Check your column rowspan, HTML errors or css datatables file.

You can also inspect the example and compare it with your code.